# Session getting destroyed after Payment gateway redirecting to success callback url in asp mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Please suggest me..
Session getting destroyed after Payment gateway redirecting to success callback URL in c#

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: Check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

Answer (score 0):

If your cookie needs to be sent on cross-site POST requests you need to set session cookie "SameSite" attribute to "None" and "Secure" flag to "true" after chrome v80.
https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site